# What are the usual results for pedestrian posture detection?

Tags: computer-vision

When talking about lane detection in a road, usually robotic computer vision system give lines in an image.

For detecting obstacles, those system give Bounding Boxes.

My question is, for pedestrian (human) pose detection, in which format are the results given usually?

Comment: probably bounding boxes ... after all, a pedestrian is an obstacle

Answer (score 1):

Typically any detected *object* would be reported with a bounding box. Then you have information for those objects, like heading, speed, etc., and you can project the bounding box's location into the future given its size and the path information.